# Customize chapter and section titles inside a tcolorbox

Tags: sectioning

I need help pls about this.

[image]

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
%%================%%
%%KHAI BÁO GÓI TOÁN%%
%%================%%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumerate}
%%================%%
%%KHAI BÁO VẼ HÌNH   %%
%%================%%
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab,tkz-linknodes}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,intersections,angles,quotes,shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\usepackage{tabvar}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
%%==========================%%
%%KHAI BÁO CANH LỀ, HYPERLINK  %%
%%==========================%%
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=1cm] {geometry}
%\usepackage[unicode, bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage[hidelinks,unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{currfile}
\definecolor{yourcolor}{HTML}{008bb2}
\newcounter{sothuong}
\def\sothuong{\stepcounter{sothuong}{\arabic{sothuong}}}
\newcommand{\sectionso}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-.5ex]current bounding box.center)},vertex/.style={anchor=base,
            circle,fill=yourcolor,text=white,minimum size=10pt,inner sep=2pt}]
\node[vertex] {\sothuong};
\end{tikzpicture} {\color{yourcolor}\bfseries #1} \\}
\begin{document}
    \sectionlama{TƯ DUY THUẬT TOÁN}
    \sectionso{Tư duy công thức}
    \sectionlama{Tư duy không tưởng}
    \sectionso{Tư duy là gì?}
    Toi không biết
    \sectionso{Tư duy là gì?}
    Toi không biết
    \sectionso{Tư duy là gì?}
    Toi không biết
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from. Also, can you please clearly what it is that you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You load tons of packages that are not really necessary here. Here is a minimal damage proposal to produce something close to your desired output.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=1cm] {geometry}
\definecolor{yourcolor}{HTML}{008bb2}
\newcounter{sothuong}
\def\sothuong{\stepcounter{sothuong}{\arabic{sothuong}}}
\newcommand{\sectionso}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-.5ex]current bounding box.center)},vertex/.style={anchor=base,
            circle,fill=yourcolor,text=white,minimum size=10pt,inner sep=2pt}]
\node[vertex] {\sothuong};
\end{tikzpicture} {\color{yourcolor}\bfseries #1}}
\newcounter{lama}
\def\lama{\stepcounter{lama}{\Roman{lama}}}
\newcommand{\sectionlama}[1]{\color{red}\bfseries\lama . #1} 

\begin{document}
\tcbsetforeverylayer{colframe=blue!75!black}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Kien\dots]
    \sectionlama{TƯ DUY THUẬT TOÁN}\\
    \sectionso{Tư duy công thức}\\
    \sectionlama{Tư duy không tưởng}\\
    \sectionso{Tư duy là gì?}\\
    Toi không biết
    \sectionso{Tư duy là gì?}\\
    Toi không biết
    \sectionso{Tư duy là gì?}\\
    Toi không biết
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Here is a version that seems to match your description and also takes into account that you were naming your command `\sectionso`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=1cm] {geometry}
\definecolor{yourcolor}{HTML}{008bb2}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {}
  {\color{red}\bfseries\Roman{chapter}}{4pt}
  {\color{red}\bfseries#1}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\titleformat{\section}
  {}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-.5ex]current bounding box.center)},vertex/.style={anchor=base,
            circle,fill=yourcolor,text=white,minimum size=10pt,inner sep=2pt}]
\node[vertex] {\arabic{section}};
\end{tikzpicture}}{3pt}
  {\color{yourcolor}\bfseries #1}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\tcbsetforeverylayer{colframe=blue!75!black}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Kien\dots]
    \chapter{TƯ DUY THUẬT TOÁN}
    \section{Tư duy công thức}
    \chapter{Tư duy không tưởng}
    \section{Tư duy là gì?}
    Toi không biết
    \section{Tư duy là gì?}
    Toi không biết
    \section{Tư duy là gì?}
    Toi không biết
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: THANKS. I want Part I number 1 2 3 Part 2 Number 1 2 3. And 1 2 3 in other line. Help me pls

Comment: @Peter I added a second example using titlesec.

Comment: @marmot You seem to understand what the question is about. Do you happen to have a suggestion for a better title of the question?

Comment: @samcarter "How to prevent a marmot from hibernating" or "Customize chapter and section titles inside a tcolorbox", whatever you like better. ;-)

Comment: @marmot Thanks! The first suggestion fits so many questions, it would be a shame to waste it for this one. I'll keep it for another occasion when there are not multiple titles to chose from :)